# MUPDF UnsupportedOperationException when open the pdf

Tags: java, android, exception, mupdf

I am using MUPDF for an android project, but there is an issue by some android users. I got report as following:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at com.odilogy.mupdf.ReaderView.getSelectedView(ReaderView.java:664)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.widget.AdapterView.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AdapterView.java:951)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.widget.AdapterView.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(AdapterView.java:926)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:704)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:4952)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:4933)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6675)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 E/AndroidRuntime( 4677):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this exception occurs by this line:

```
public View getSelectedView() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
}
```

I have no idea how to fix that, anybody can help? thanks!

Regards

Comment: You should investigate why this method getSelectedView() executed. If you just don't want to throw the exception, you can comment it out //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");

Answer (score 5):

just fixed with:

```
public View getSelectedView() {
//throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");

return null;
```

Comment: That's patching over the symptom, not fixing the problem.

Comment: Actually that was the solution given by [MuPDF team](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695132#c1)

Comment: I am getting this error only in new Android versions (exemple 7.0).