# UnsupportedOperationException - Random Error - OnBackPressed

Tags: android, mupdf, onbackpressed, unsupportedoperation

I am getting unsupported operation exception while running my Android Code, RANDOMLY. Once this exception is thrown, my application is crashed. How to handle the same , and what is the basic cause of this EXCEPTION to be thrown.

Example 1:

```
@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
}
```

Example 2:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(slideContent.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
        slideContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(searchAutoCompleteText.getText().toString().length()>0)
        searchAutoCompleteText.setText("");
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
com.artifex.mupdfdemo.ReaderView.getSelectedView(ReaderView.java:751)
android.widget.AdapterView.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AdapterView.java:1014)
android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5150)
android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5135)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7463)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The above written are few scenarios where I get UNSUPPORTEDOperationException and the Application Crashed. Please let me know the ROOT CAUSE, if anybody knows the same.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem with MuPDF.

Comment: Can we see full logcat?

Comment: looked up that any method is depreciated bcoz some times it is due to that??

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ Updated my question with the LogCat. Thanks

Comment: What's line ReaderView.java:751?

Comment: Try [returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21181085/1777090) instead of throwing exception in getSelectedView

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported"); -- This is the line number 751

Answer (score 6):

return null instead of `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getContext().getString(R.string.not_supported));
        return null;
}
```

check [this](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695132)